# Check whether elements in one array exist in another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of 17 million non-unique items and want to check if they exist in a set of unique items.

```
Large_array=[1,2, 3, 4,...17000000 ]
Dictionary= [1,2,3,4,...15000000]
```

I tried list in operation:

```
[I in Dictionary for I in Large_array)]
```

and numpy's `isin` and `in1d`, but it takes it forever.

```
np.isin(Large_array, Dictionary)

np.in1d(Large_array, Dictionary)
```

I would like to know if there is a faster way to accomplish the same thing.

The output I need is an array of the same size as `Large_array`, with `result[i]` set to true iff `Large_array[i]` exists in `Dictionary`, and I would like a fast way to create it.

Comment: Please provide a code sample or an example that can be reproduced https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: a = set([1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8])
b = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])  a -b

Comment: When you say - `check if they exist`, are you checking for ANY or ALL presence? Also, are those items integers / positive integers / any other specific scenario?

Comment: @Divakar I wanted to produce a mask of true/false values showing if the item exists in the array of items set as dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by pandas merge inner join, cutting out all the items in larger array which were not present in the array of unique items (can call it dictionary)

```
pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')
```

But first convert the numpy arrays to pandas DataFrames.

The methods I tried to use first would take 1300 hours, but merge took just 1 minute.